# Cannot establish successful connection to RADIUS protocol despite correct configuration

Tags: security, windows-server-2019, radius, network-security, aaa-security-protocol

so im working on my final year project: Study and Implementation of the RADIUS Protocol.

First of all, let me give you an overview of our current configuration. We have successfully completed the installation and configuration of all the necessary roles to implement the RADIUS protocol. These roles include AD DS, DHCP, DNS, NPS, and AD CS. Additionally, we have taken care to disable the firewall to allow unrestricted access to RADIUS ports 1812 and 1813. We have also verified the connectivity between the server and the router by successfully pinging.

However, despite these preparations, we are experiencing difficulties in connecting to the network via the router, and the server is not listening. We have checked and confirmed that the IP addresses are correctly configured and consistent between the server and the router. That being said, we are still unable to establish a successful connection.

To provide you with a better understanding of our current configuration and the nature of the problem, I have attached a video detailing our server configuration, as well as a Wireshark capture to show packet exchanges.

We would greatly appreciate any assistance you can provide in resolving this issue. If you need any further information or additional details, please let me know.

VMware : Windows Server 2019 (Domain Controller)
Domaine : pfe.local
IP : 192.168.10.2/24
Gateway : 192.168.10.10
DNS : 192.168.10.2
DHCP : pool 192.168.10.50 - 192.168.10.100
Routeur :
IP : 192.168.10.10
RADIUS server : 192.168.10.2:1812
shared key : PFEadmin2023
WPS is Disabled

Desactivate Firewall
RADIUC client with and without VPN
Address IP

Answer (score 0):

I didnt read you mentioning if you added the router as a RADIUS client, and configured it properly to trust NPS.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).